# regex results from a csv to a csv output

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv

I would like to save my results in my csv. But somehow it remains empty. But if I write the same output not in the csv and only `print` I get my results As I would like it to have.

```
import re
import glob
import os
## is the second script for matchParser.py, match the results for Duration in ms digit
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('output.csv')]
for result in lines:

    match = re.search(r'(!?\s.\d[Request completed in\s])', result)
    if match: print match.group(0)
```

but this version with the output_csv is not working, i dont know why..

```
import re
import glob
import os

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('output.csv')]
for result in lines:

    match = re.search(r'(!?\s.\d[Request completed in\s])', result)
    with open('outputREGEX5.csv', "w") as output_csv:
        if match: output_csv.write(match.group(0))
```

I also get the following error:

```
output.write(match.group(0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Am grateful for any help.

--
**EDIT**
My `print` Output:

```
 44 
 37 
 53 
 35 
 17 
 35 
 25 
 27 
 50 
 31 
 27 
 36 
 17 
 66 
 46 
 41 
 38 
 23 
 33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
open('outputREGEX5.csv', "w")
```

empties the file. Only open the file once outside of the loop, instead of opening it every iteration.

```
with open('outputREGEX5.csv', "w") as output_csv:
    for result in lines:
        match = re.search(r'(!?\s.\d[Request completed in\s])', result)
        if match: output_csv.write(match.group(0) + '\n')
```

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more precisely and say exactly where I should place it? I am a newbie in python

Comment: Almost... the `match = ...` line should be before the `if match:`, and at the same indent level.

Comment: its working! but the entrys are not in newline as in the print version. how can I add a \n So that every iteration is written into a new line?

Comment: @harun literally just by adding a \n to the thing that you're writing. Come on, give it a try.

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately without success. Always get this error: NameError: name 'match' is not defined :/

Comment: I was close. :) Thanks for your help.